# how to write makefile for c++ vs proje

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, makefile, compilation

I need to write a makefile for a c++ visual-studio project running on windows.
I have only 5 files that I need to compile:

```
main,  Board.cpp, Board.h, Node.cpp, Node.h
```

I want to use the "make" command in cmd and compile it all.
I don't know how to write proper makefile for that, while searching I've found this [Write makefile for .cpp and .hpp c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231330/write-makefile-for-cpp-and-hpp-c) but it is not my case..
HELP??

Comment: How would you do it on the command line (i.e. *without Make)?

Comment: I heard there are "nmake" and such, so I mentioned I want to use "make"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp Board.cpp Node.cpp
```

Comment: No need to compile all header files ? and does that makefile necessarily work on all windows-OS computers? and btw, does it matter to makefile if I need to read or write from an external txt file ?

Comment: header files are never compiled and yes, even other systems like linux. it doesn't matter if you read/write external files

Comment: Do note the tags on the question.... Visual Studio doesn't come with g++.

Comment: You can replace g++ by any compiler

Comment: and how do i know which compiler I need for my visual studio 2015 ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't really matter which compiler you are using, Visual studio has its own compiler. You can build a visual studio solution directly by replacing the g++ main.cpp Board.cpp Node.cpp with msbuild your_project.sln /Flags as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498106/how-do-i-compile-a-visual-studio-project-from-the-command-line